# How to filter the special characters, not including the French letters, using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I use `replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ")` can filter all special character,
but I don't want filter the French letters.

Comment: an example would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
/[^\w\sàâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒ]/g
```

You don't need special treatment for the `_` as it is included in `\w`

**Reference**

[French orthography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_alphabet)