# Replace inside matched string with Notepad++ and regex

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have some lines in a text file :

```
Joëlle;Dupont;123456
Alex;Léger;134234
```

And I want to replace them by :

```
Joëlle;Dupont;123456;joelle.dupont@mail.com
Alex;Léger;134234;alex.leger@mail.com
```

I want to replace all characters with accents (é, ë…) by characters without accents (e, e…) but **only on the mail adress**, only on a part of the line.

I know I can use `\L\E` to change uppercase letter into lowercase letter but it's not the only thing I have to do.

I used :

```
(.*?);(.*?);(\d*?)\n
```

To replace it by :

```
$1;$2;$3;\L$1.$2@mail.com\E\n
```

But it wouldn't replace characters with accents :

```
Joëlle;Dupont;123456;joëlle.dupont@mail.com
Alex;Léger;134234;alex.léger@mail.com
```

If you have any idea how I could do this with Notepad++, even with more than one replacement, maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your whole population, but you could use the below to replace the variations of `e` with an `e`:

```
[\xE8-\xEB](?!.*;)
```

And replace with `e`.

[I got the range above from [this webpage](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html), taking the column names]

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/jG9aH2/3)

This regex matches any `è`, `é`, `ê` or `ë` and replaces them with an `e`, if there is no `;` on the same line after it.

---

For variations of `o`:

```
[\xF2-\xF6](?!.*;)
```

For `c` (there's only one, so you can also put in `ç` directly):

```
\xE7(?!.*;)
```

For `a`:

```
[\xE0-\xE5](?!.*;)
```

Comment: They are French letters, and there are also others letters like ç, à, ô… to replace them by c, a, o… respectively. But most importantly, the thing I want to do is for example replace é by e, but only in the mail adress, without modifying the rest of the line.

Comment: @Minizarbi Added for the other letters and replace each with the 'main' letter. The regex only modifies the last 'column' in your data if `;` is the delimiter. If you have more than one `column` of email addresses, then you might use `(?=[^;@]*@)` instead of `(?!.*;)`.

Comment: I didn't know the (?!…) or (?=…) and I think it's the solution to my problem, so it works. And I didn't know the two websites you linked.

Comment: @Minizarbi If you want me to explain how these work, let me know :) They are called 'lookarounds' in general, and more specifically, `(?= ... )` is a positive lookahead and `(?! ... )` is a negative lookahead. You can also search those terms on the internet, that's where I learned those in the first place :)

Comment: I didn't understand in the first place so I looked here : http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions and now I understand, so thank you :)

Comment: +1, Great research, why no upvotes...? Could be further simplified for legibility, for instance `[è-ë](?!.*;)` which would work in N++.

Comment: Ah, dug this one up I answered a few days ago: [French letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623395/how-to-filter-the-special-characters-not-including-the-french-letters-using-re/24623419#24623419) Leaving it here for reference if someone feels like starting a French collection.